# Can I use regular mouse with my MacBook Pro 2011 using Mac OS Lion?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, mouse

I saw one of my friends using a regular A4Tech OP-620D USB mouse with a MacBook Pro 2010 and Mac OS 10.6.7.  I tried to use a local brand USB mouse on my machine but it didn't work. It showed properties in preferences but the mouse was not functioning.  Therefore can I use a branded USB mouse on OS X Lion? Also can it be a bluetooth or 2.4G wireless mouse?

Comment: Mine works fine. And a friend of mine uses wireless mouse. :)

Comment: @Kjuly that is great but I wonder why local brand mouse didn't work. Is there need to install any drivers?

Comment: Maybe it's your mouse problem, or the USB issue, not sure. I tried to use local brand mouse(HP) and it works fine. :)

Comment: @Kjuly, I will buy A4tech mouse today and give it a try, hope it works

Comment: Maybe you can bring your macbook together with you. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used everything from wired Bluetooth (incl. Razer Naga and a bluetooth Logitech) on all my Macs. All of the buttons on the Naga work via a control panel interface, and I have had no problem. Nevertheless, the "mouse feel" still isn't up to the standards of the native Mac mouses. No matter the setting, the acceleration goes from too slow to too fast in a heartbeat. It's usable, but I keep going back to my Magic Mouse for everything but gaming (in games where I need those extra buttons).

Comment: Bought A4Tech mouse yesterday, it worked, but I agree the magic of magic mouse is good, but its design is not good, long time use makes my palm strain.